# Animation should play only on pressing the button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an issue when playing animation in Unity. I made a transaction and set a bool on the animation. The issue here is that if I have an animation on a loop it won't stop. If I unloop it, it would play only once. What I actually want from this is to play only when the player presses the button. Right now my code looks like this. I tried to set the bool to false in different places, but it didn't have the right effect. I would appreciate any idea. Thanks

```
private void Inflations()
    {
        inflationTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        //if hands are in mount area inflate
        if (OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.Any))
        {
            if (inflationTimer <= 0 && rightHand.inflated)
            {
                if (inflated)
                {
                    inflationTimer = inflationSpawn;
                    inflated = false;
                    inflationAnimator.SetBool("Pressed", true);

                    //we can add inflations only if they are under 2 and if the button is pressed and released
                    inflations++;
                }
                else
                {
                    inflationAnimator.SetBool("Pressed", false);
                }
                tempo.SetInflations(inflations);
            }
        }


        if (OVRInput.GetUp(OVRInput.Button.Any))
        {
            if (!inflated)
            {
                inflated = true;
            }
        }
        if (inflations >= 2)
        {
            inflationAnimator.SetBool("Pressed", false);
            state = stueState.TakeInflator;
            inflationsDone = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is inflation part of the animation? Or is it a game mechanic? Also; do you want the animation to keep playing in loop after release of the button-press, or only while being pressed?

Comment: May I see your Animator (State Machine)? You need two states to be in.

Comment: @ecco Depends on what she wants to achieve; hence my questions.

Comment: @XenoRo I guess she doesn't want it to loop all the time, as she called it an issue.

Comment: @ecco "What I actually want from this is to play only when the player presses the button." - Can be ambiguous between meaning to only start playing when the player presses the button, but continue after, in which case it can be done with one state; or to only play while being pressed, in which case it can still be done with one state if it can "freeze" where it stops or if it can "jump" to a default, or needs two if it should return to a default smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ecco is right, you need two states for it

Without seeing your Animator Controller, you could use something like this;

```cs
//...
Stack<Action> _animations = new Stack<Action>();

private void Inflations()
{
   // ...
   if (OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.Any))
   {
       if(inflated){
          // your code
          _animations.Push(() => inflationAnimator.SetBool("Pressed", true));
          // ...
       }
   }
}

private void Update(){
   if(_animations.Count > 0){
      var currentAnimation = _animations.Pop();
      currentAnimation();
   }
}
```

This eliminates the need for a lot of if checks and is nice to use.

Note: I used ***lambda expression*** there for simplicity. You can read more about it in [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-csharp-features-5-lambda-expression). And you can read more about ***Stack*** containers [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-stack)

The update function is gonna check if there are any animations in Stack, if there are, it will automatically execute it once and remove it from the stack.